# changing value in javascript object iterated using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK So I have this piece of code :

```
var el = {a:"b","isSel":true};
$.each(el,function(k,v){
  if(k=="isSel"){
    v=false
  }
})
console.log(el);
```

but that doesn't change isSel to false... any clues?

Comment: Why would you need to iterate? `if ("isSel" in el) el["isSel"]=false;`

Comment: There isn't any JSON here.  You just have standard old Javascript objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to

```
var el = {a:"b","isSel":true};
$.each(el,function(k,v){
  if(k=="isSel"){
    el[k]=false // <= this sets the property named k of el
  }
})
console.log(el);
```

Note that if you just want to change the property named `"isSel"` of el, you don't have to iterate : you may simply do

```
el["isSel"] = false;
```

or

```
el.isSel = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for looping. The value can be accessed as follows:

```
el.isSel = false;
```

or

```
el["isSel"] = false;
```

Comment: Yeah I actually have a lot of nested properties, the JSON I'm handling is a bit more complicated so have to loop inward